# Images in ListView are repeated

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm parsing vk's group wall. Some posts have photos(from 1 to 10), some don't have. And I need to display them. However, all the images are repeated. And I can't make them appear correctly. I'm using Picasso at the moment. It says it can process ListView images, however it doesn't. Other ways I foun on google don't work either. The question is how to process images correctly. Here is a piece of code that is responsible for photo.

```
private void place_photos(View view, ArrayList<VKPhoto> photos) {
    int pcount = photos.size();
    final View v = view;
    TableRow first = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.first_row);
    TableRow second = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.second_row);
    TableRow third = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.third_row);

    for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
            String url = photos.get(i).photo_807;
            img.setTag(url);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(img);
            if (first != null)
                first.addView(img);
        }
        if (i == 2 || i == 3) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
            String url = photos.get(i).photo_807;
            img.setTag(url);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(img);
            if (second != null)
                second.addView(img);
        }
        if (i > 3) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
            String url = photos.get(i).photo_807;
            img.setTag(url);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(img);
            if (third != null)
                third.addView(img);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how it's called in getView method:

```
if (post.attachments.hasPhoto) {
        place_photos(v, post.attachments.photos);
} else {
        viewHolder.photo_wrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**UPD**
Here is the full adapter code: https://gist.github.com/alexbat98/7f22598e7e73d301a4ef

Comment: If you using custom adapter paste that code here

Comment: @Kat-hat uploaded to Gist

Comment: I'm not sure but do you set the viewholder.photo ?

Comment: try to use this "AndroidQuery" awesome library for load image from server in async https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: I didn't find  viewHolder.photo_wrapper in Gist. And is this imageview(viewHolder.photo_wrapper) is repeating?

Comment: @Kat-hat I've just renamed it to viewHolder.photo_stub. It's a TableLayout. I add images dinamically there.

Comment: @Haresh I'm not sure it will help me. I've already tried a number of libraries including AsynkTask classes I found on stackoverflow. It's probably something wrong with my adapter and view recycling. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Comment: `third.addView(img);` is not something you want to do in a `ListAdapter`. Views are recycled, meaning this may be called several times for several rows, but on the same view. This is what the whole `convertView` and `ViewHolder` business are about. I don't quite understand the use of this `place_photos` method, but your image views should be defined in the row item layout, like the `viewHolder.photo`.

Comment: (is it because you have a dynamic number of images in each line? in which case you'd simply have to remove the children of first, second and third before adding imageview again)

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for advice. It's really better now, hoewer I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ImageView img;
```

inside ViewHolder class and then use it as

```
 viewHolder.img = viewHolder.photo;
     viewHolder.img.setTag(photo_100);
     imageLoader.DisplayImage(photo_100,  viewHolder.img);
```

Comment: Actually viewHolder.photo is a user avatar. And I dont have problems with it. The trouble is inside place_photos method. Here is a screenshot: https://db.tt/9PvaoRPS

Comment: Sry but the code looks little messy actually...what you can do is that the imageview in adapter which you find is repeating, put that into ViewHolder class and use the same as I do above for "img"(ImageView)

Comment: yes, code is a bit messy. But how can I use ViewHolder? I create that views dinamically. So, I dont have them in my xml layout and I don't know how many photos I will have.

Answer (score 0):

Issue should be due to the `ListView` recycle.

Try to override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType`

If your view types are different then return the type count, e.g. if 3 different types,then

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

And, then tell the `ListView` which position of item is different from other, e.g., if position 0 and 1 are different from other items then change it like this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    // return a unique number
    if(position == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(position == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```